# Hosting companies that allow hosting a laravel application on tor

Tags: configuration, onion-services

Are there any hosting companies that offer tor services for hosting a laravel application. Is it even possible to host a laravel application over tor? Also, compile my laravel application and then host it if there are no companies offering such a service.

Answer (score 0):

You will find very few services for specifically hosting Tor services at all and I don't think you'll find any with a preinstalled Laravel configuration. Your best bet us to:

1. Get a Linux VPS
2. Set up tor to provide a service on port 80 (or another port if your prefer)
3. Install Laravel on the VPS and compile your site using the port from step #2.

I'm not very familiar with Laravel or how secure it is. Is there a chance that it can leak your real IP or other information that you want to keep secure? If so, then it might not be the best approach. If not, then you don't even need a VPS for testing. Try it on your own computer or create a Linux VM to try it there. If it works, then pay for a VPS.